# Problem in calling function as a send parameter in Kotlin retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, observable, retrofit

The problem what I faced is, I do not know how to call query parameters(id) in the following functions in presenter and view classes. Architecture is mvp.

My API URL is:: http://soanitravel.com/api/bookingdetail?id=2

My api declarations::
const val BASE_URL = "http://soanitravel.com/api/"
const val BOOKINGDETAILS = "bookingdetail/{id}"

I tried to get api data like this way::

```
//GetFunction
     @GET(Apiurl.BOOKINGDETAILS)
        fun postBookingDetails(@Header("Authorization") token: BookingDetailsResponse, @Path("id") id: Int?): Observable<BookingDetailsResponse><br>
```

```
//Model class
     fun getBookingDetails(info: BookingDetailsResponse,id: Int): Observable<BookingDetailsResponse> {
        return webservice.postBookingDetails(info, id)
    }
```

```
//presenter class
    private fun DashboardRequest() {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            bookingDetailsModel.getBookingDetails(bookingDetailsView.getBookingDetailsRequest())  /// here red errors says id to put in getBookingDetailsRequest())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(this::dashboardSuccess, this::dashboardError)
        )
    }
```

```
 //View class
       fun getBookingDetailsRequest(): BookingDetailsResponse {
            return BookingDetailsResponse()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit support @Path and @Query parameters. You need to use @Query here.

```
@GET(Apiurl.BOOKINGDETAILS)
fun postBookingDetails(@Header("Authorization") token: BookingDetailsResponse,
     @Query("id") id: Int?): Observable<BookingDetailsResponse>
```

For better understanding

URI/Path param.

```
GET bookingdetail/2
```

Query Parameter.

```
GET bookingdetail?id=2
```